# Convergence in $L^\infty$ norm and continuous function

Tags: functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, metric-spaces

Let $\mathcal{C}(T)$ be the set of continuous functions on $T$, which is a metric space under the norm $\left\|f\right\|_{\infty}=\sup_{t\in T}\left|f(t)\right|$. Suppose $\{X_{n}\}$ and $X$ take their values in $\mathcal{C}(T)$ and that you have shown that $X_{n}\stackrel{L}{\longrightarrow} X$ in $L^{\infty}(T)$. Show this implies $X_{n}\stackrel{L}{\longrightarrow}X$ in $\mathcal{C}(T)$ as well.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow the terminology, so just to make sure: is the question to prove that the uniform limit of continuous functions is continuous?

Comment: I would say $\left\|f\right\|_{\infty}=\sup_{t\in T}\left|f(t)\right|$ is the usual norm for $C(T)$, and if "convergence in $C(T)$" means something other than convergence in this norm, you will have to tell us what it is.

Comment: Also, by "$X$ takes its values in $C(T)$" do you mean $X$ is an element of $C(T)$?

Comment: This is a well written question by our professor, but I don't really understand it

Comment: Do you understand the answer below or is there still something unclear?

Comment: Not really, I don't understand why 'this also means'...

Answer (score 5):

$X_n\rightarrow X$ in $L^\infty(T)$ means $\|X_n-X\|_\infty\rightarrow 0$. But this also means $X_n\rightarrow X$ in $C(T)$ the only difference being that the $\sup$ in the definition of $L^\infty$ is an essential supremum, i.e. allowing for exceptional sets of measure zero. For continuous functions however, the essential supremum equals the  ordinary supremum.

Comment: Is that dependent on the properties of $T$? (Or rather, should clarifications be made regarding $L^\infty$ depending on the properties of $T$?)

Comment: Typically, $T$ is compact, so that $C(T)$ makes sense as a Banach space with the supremum norm.

Comment: $T$ is such a unique notation for a general compact space, though. And considering how isolated points complicate continuity vs. essential supremum...